# content query web part in page layout sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, page-layout, cqwp

Is it possible to add a cqwp in a page layout?
Ive tried to move the webpart from the page to the page layout used in the page. But In the second case i dont see anything.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported to add instance of CQWP into Page Layout.

Possible reasons why CQWP results are not visible:

- Javascript/CSS that affect the visibility of web part
- Verify source settings for web part. In case if page and page layouts located on different sites and the source property is configured to `Show items from the following list` or `Show items from the following site and all subsites` then this could be the reason. In both cases for for source property the **relative path** could be specified.

[image]